# How do I delete a google chart and replace it with a new one in a google app?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have searched everywhere I can not come up with a solution to this. I am trying to make this code display a chart every time a user clicks "submit" (that part works). The problem comes in with the user clicks submit more then once. It showing the chart multiple times. How do I make it delete the last chart and update it with the new one?

```
function doGet() {
  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("some title");

  var grid = uiApp.createGrid(3, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, uiApp.createLabel('Lablel 1'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, uiApp.createLabel('Lablel 2'));

  var panel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel();

  panel.add(grid);

  var button = uiApp.createButton('submit');
  var handler = uiApp.createServerHandler('b');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  panel.add(button);
  uiApp.add(panel);

  return uiApp;
 }

function b(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  //gets all my chart data
  var chart = getchartdata()

  //Add chart
  app.add(chart)

  var uiApp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  uiApp.close();

  return uiApp;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is to have a separate panel for your chart and clear it each time before you add a chart. 
The VerticalPanel widget also has a remove method you can use. 
See the code below for the first option I suggested

```
function doGet(){
  /* All your other code here */
  uiApp.add(panel);
  var chartPanel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel().setId('chartPanel'); 
  uiApp.add(chartPanel);

  return uiApp;
}

function b(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  //gets all my chart data
  var chart = getchartdata()

  /* Clear chart Panel */
  var chartPanel = app.getElementById('chartPanel');
  chartPanel.clear(); 

  //Add chart
  chartPanel.add(chart)

  var uiApp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  uiApp.close();

  return uiApp;
}
```

*P.S: I'm not sure why you have two different variables app and uiApp for the same thing. Although not in your case, it can lead to confusion and problems.*

Comment: Thanks Srik just what I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Noting that this question is now six years old, my answer applies more to deleting charts from a `Sheet` object, and *not* deleting charts from a panel in a `UiApp`, especially that `UiApp` has been deprecated:

***"Warning: The UI service was deprecated on December 11, 2014. To create user interfaces, use the HTML service instead."***

This answer does *not* apply to deleting charts that were inserted into an `HtmlService` HTML dialog.

So, for those readers wanting to delete charts from a `Sheet` object, the following code works great:

```
function deleteAllChartsFromSheet(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var chartsSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // TODO: validate param sheetName
  var n = chartsSheet.getCharts().length;
  for (var i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {  // note: delete them in reverse order!
    var chart = chartsSheet.getCharts()[i];
    chartsSheet.removeChart(chart);
  }
}
```